# Why is my pointerEventData.position always Vector2.zero?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing on a script using a [`PointerEventData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData.html) for passing pointer events like e.g. [`pointerDownHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents-pointerDownHandler.html), [`pointerUpHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents-pointerUpHandler.html), [`dragHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents-dragHandler.html) etc. events to raycasted objects using [`ExecuteEvents.Execute`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute.html) e.g. like

```c#
ExecuteEvents.Execute(sometargetGameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
```

Basically everything worked fine for e.g. `Button`s but currently I'm stuck at dragging `ScrollRect` with a strange behaviour. I need to pass in the [`PointerEventData.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData-position.html) so what I tried

in `Update` among others I have the lines

```c#
pointerPosition3D = _laser.transform.position + _laser.transform.forward * dist / 2f;
pointerPosition2D = _camera.WorldToScreenPoint(pointerPosition3D);
_pointerEventData.position = pointerPosition2D;
_lastPointerPosition = _pointerEventData.position;
```

but the `_pointerEventData.position` always keeps being `(0.0, 0.0)`.

When debugging line by line I can clearly see that e.g.

> pointerPosition3D = `(-0.177, 0.304, 0.9999)`
>   pointerPosition2D = `(74.28255, 153.9007)`

however already in the next line

```c#
_lastPointerPosition = _pointerEventData.position;
```

> _pointerEventData.position = `(0.0, 0.0)`

[image]

How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

---

#### Further background:

I'm saw the idea of [SteamVR Laser Pointer Menus](https://unity3d.college/2017/06/17/steamvr-laser-pointer-menus/) and created a `LaserPointer` class based on their idea with `steamvr_laserpointer.cs` and `VRUIItem`. Here is the full class I have so far and as said for `Button` and usual 3D Colliders this already works great (for debugging I currently set `isPressed` via the Inspector):

```c#
#define USE_CUSTOM_EDITOR

using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
#if UNITY_EDITOR && USE_CUSTOM_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

public class LaserPointerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Inspector

    [Header("Pointer Settings")]
    [Tooltip("Should the LaserPointer origin have an offset to the controller position (in local coordinates)?")]
    [SerializeField] private bool useOffset;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 offset = Vector3.zero;

    [Tooltip("The maximal distance of the laser pointer (in Unity Units)")]
    [SerializeField] private float maxPointerDistance = 5f;

    [Tooltip("Should the laser have a Collider attached?\nUseful for e.g. directly using OnTriggerEnter\n\nNote: This will use Physics.RaycastAll which is less efficient.")]
    [SerializeField] private bool useCollider;
    [Tooltip("Should the laser Collider be a trigger?\nHas to be disabled to e.g. use OnCollisionEnter")]
    [SerializeField] private bool colliderIsTrigger;
    [Tooltip("Should the laser additionally have a RigidBody?\nRequired for some types of collisions.")]
    [SerializeField] private bool useRigidBody;

    [Header("Style Settings")]
    [Tooltip("Should the laser change its Color when pressed")]
    [SerializeField] private bool changeColor;
    [Tooltip("Should the laser change its thickness when pressed")]
    [SerializeField] private bool changeThickness;
    [Tooltip("Color of the Laser in idle")]
    [SerializeField] private Color idleColor = Color.red;
    [Tooltip("Color of the beam when pressed")]
    [SerializeField] private Color pressedColor = Color.green;
    [Tooltip("Thickness of the laser beam")]
    [SerializeField] private float idleThickness = 0.005f;
    [Tooltip("Thickness of the laser beam when pressed")]
    [SerializeField] private float pressedThickness = 0.007f;

    [Header("Debug")]
    [SerializeField] private bool isPressed;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 pointerPosition3D;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 pointerPosition2D;

#if UNITY_EDITOR && USE_CUSTOM_EDITOR
    [CustomEditor(typeof(LaserPointerController))]
    private class LaserPointerControllerEditor : Editor
    {
        private SerializedProperty useOffset;
        private SerializedProperty offset;

        private SerializedProperty maxPointerDistance;

        private SerializedProperty useCollider;
        private SerializedProperty colliderIsTrigger;
        private SerializedProperty useRigidBody;

        private SerializedProperty changeColor;
        private SerializedProperty changeThickness;
        private SerializedProperty idleColor;
        private SerializedProperty pressedColor;
        private SerializedProperty idleThickness;
        private SerializedProperty pressedThickness;

        private SerializedProperty _isPressed;
        private SerializedProperty pointerPosition3D;
        private SerializedProperty pointerPosition2D;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            useOffset = serializedObject.FindProperty("useOffset");
            offset = serializedObject.FindProperty("offset");

            maxPointerDistance = serializedObject.FindProperty("maxPointerDistance");
            useCollider = serializedObject.FindProperty("useCollider");
            colliderIsTrigger = serializedObject.FindProperty("colliderIsTrigger");
            useRigidBody = serializedObject.FindProperty("useRigidBody");

            changeColor = serializedObject.FindProperty("changeColor");
            changeThickness = serializedObject.FindProperty("changeThickness");
            idleColor = serializedObject.FindProperty("idleColor");
            pressedColor = serializedObject.FindProperty("pressedColor");
            idleThickness = serializedObject.FindProperty("idleThickness");
            pressedThickness = serializedObject.FindProperty("pressedThickness");

            _isPressed = serializedObject.FindProperty("isPressed");
            pointerPosition3D = serializedObject.FindProperty("pointerPosition3D");
            pointerPosition2D = serializedObject.FindProperty("pointerPosition2D");
        }

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            serializedObject.Update();

            DrawScriptField();

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(useOffset);
            if (useOffset.boolValue)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(offset);
                EditorGUILayout.Space();
            }

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(maxPointerDistance);

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(useCollider);
            if (useCollider.boolValue)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(colliderIsTrigger);
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(useRigidBody);
            }
            else
            {
                colliderIsTrigger.boolValue = true;
                useRigidBody.boolValue = false;
            }

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(changeColor);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(changeThickness);

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(idleColor);
            if (changeColor.boolValue) EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(pressedColor);

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(idleThickness);
            if (changeThickness.boolValue) EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(pressedThickness);

            if (EditorApplication.isPlayingOrWillChangePlaymode)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_isPressed);

                EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
                {
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(pointerPosition3D);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(pointerPosition2D);
                }
                EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
            }

            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        private void DrawScriptField()
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
            {
                EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Script", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour((LaserPointerController)target), typeof(LaserPointerController), false);
            }
            EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

            EditorGUILayout.Space();
        }
    }
#endif

    #endregion Inspector


    #region Public Members

    public Vector3 PointerPosition3D
    {
        get { return pointerPosition3D; }
    }

    public Vector2 PointerPosition2D
    {
        get { return pointerPosition2D; }
    }

    public bool IsPressed
    {
        get { return isPressed; }
    }

    public Transform CurrentlyHoveredTransform
    {
        get { return _currentlyHovered; }
    }

    #endregion Public Members


    #region Private Members

    private Transform _holder;
    private Transform _laser;
    private Transform _currentlyHovered;
    private Material _laserMaterial;

    private PointerEventData _pointerEventData
    {
        get
        {
            return new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current)
            {
                // most Unity comonents e.g. the ScrollRect expect this to be Left
                // otherwise they ignore pointer input
                button = PointerEventData.InputButton.Left
            };
        }
    }
    private Vector2 _lastPointerPosition;
    private bool _isDragging;
    private bool _lastPressed;
    private Camera _camera;

    #endregion Private Members


    #region MonoBehaviour Messages
    private void Awake()
    {
        _holder = new GameObject("LaserHolder").transform;
        _holder.parent = transform;
        _holder.localScale = Vector3.one;
        _holder.localPosition = useOffset ? offset : Vector3.zero;
        _holder.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;

        _laser = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube).transform;
        var collider = _laser.GetComponent<Collider>();

        if (!useCollider)
        {
            Destroy(_laser.GetComponent<Collider>());
        }
        else
        {
            collider.isTrigger = colliderIsTrigger;
        }

        if (useRigidBody)
        {
            var rigidBody = _laser.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rigidBody.useGravity = false;
            rigidBody.isKinematic = true;
        }

        _laser.name = "LaserPointer";
        _laser.transform.parent = _holder;
        _laser.transform.localScale = new Vector3(idleThickness, idleThickness, maxPointerDistance);
        _laser.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, maxPointerDistance / 2f);
        _laser.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;

        _laserMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Color")) { color = idleColor };
        _laser.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = _laserMaterial;

        _camera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _holder.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _holder.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        //TODO uncomment this in order to get the isPressed from the according controller
        //TODO for example like
        //isPressed = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger);
        // or
        //isPressed = MLInput.GetController(MLInput.Hand.Left).State.ButtonState[(int)MLInputControllerButton.Bumper] == 1;

        // Initially the dist is the maximum pointer distance
        var dist = maxPointerDistance;

        // create the ray from the laserpointer origin
        var ray = new Ray(_holder.position, _holder.forward);

        var hit = new RaycastHit();

        // If using a Collider we have to ignore the Collider of the LaserPointer itself
        if (useCollider)
        {
            var hits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray, maxPointerDistance);
            hit = hits.FirstOrDefault(h => h.transform != _laser.transform);
        }
        else
        {
            Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxPointerDistance);
        }

        // Are we hitting something?
        if (hit.transform)
        {
            // ignore if still pressing the trigger
            if (!isPressed)
            {
                // Are we hitting something different to what we hit before?
                if (_currentlyHovered && _currentlyHovered != hit.transform)
                {
                    ExecuteEvents.Execute(_currentlyHovered.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerExitHandler);

                    _currentlyHovered = null;
                }

                // Are we hitting something new?
                if (_currentlyHovered != hit.transform)
                {
                    ExecuteEvents.Execute(hit.transform.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerEnterHandler);

                    _currentlyHovered = hit.transform;
                }
            }

            if (_currentlyHovered == hit.transform)
            {
                // If we are hitting something correct the dist value
                if (hit.distance < maxPointerDistance)
                {
                    dist = hit.distance;
                }

                if (isPressed)
                {
                    HandlePointerDown(hit.transform);
                }
                else
                {
                    HandlePointerUp(hit.transform);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!isPressed && _currentlyHovered)
            {
                HandlePointerUp(_currentlyHovered, true);

                ExecuteEvents.Execute(_currentlyHovered.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerExitHandler);

                _currentlyHovered = null;
            }
        }

        // Apply changes in the thickness and set the laser dimensions using the dist
        var thickness = !changeThickness || !isPressed ? idleThickness : pressedThickness;
        _laser.transform.localScale = new Vector3(thickness, thickness, dist);
        _laser.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, dist / 2f);

        // Apply color changes
        if (changeColor) _laserMaterial.color = isPressed ? pressedColor : idleColor;

        // Update the pointerEventData
        pointerPosition3D = _laser.transform.position + _laser.transform.forward * dist / 2f;
        pointerPosition2D = _camera.WorldToScreenPoint(pointerPosition3D);
        _pointerEventData.position = pointerPosition2D;
        _pointerEventData.delta = _pointerEventData.position - _lastPointerPosition;
        _lastPointerPosition = _pointerEventData.position;

        _lastPressed = isPressed;
    }

    #endregion MonoBehaviour Messages


    #region Private Methods

    private void HandlePointerDown(Component target)
    {
        if (!target) return;

        // only call once if IsPressed changed its value this frame
        if (_lastPressed != isPressed)
        {
            // Try pointerClickHandler, only use submitHandler as fallback
            // e.g. UI.Button implements both ... would lead to duplicate clicks
            var done = ExecuteEvents.Execute(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerClickHandler);
            if (!done) ExecuteEvents.Execute(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.submitHandler);

            ExecuteEvents.Execute(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
            ExecuteEvents.Execute(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.selectHandler);
            ExecuteEvents.Execute(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.initializePotentialDrag);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!_isDragging)
            {
                // in the first frame use beginDragHandler
                ExecuteEvents.Execute(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.beginDragHandler);
                _isDragging = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // later use dragHandler
                ExecuteEvents.Execute(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandlePointerUp(Component target, bool forceInvoke = false)
    {
        if (!target) return;

        // only call once if IsPressed changed its value this frame
        // or forceInvoke is set
        if (_lastPressed != isPressed || forceInvoke)
        {
            ExecuteEvents.Execute(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);
            ExecuteEvents.Execute(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.deselectHandler);
            ExecuteEvents.Execute(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.endDragHandler);
            ExecuteEvents.Execute(target.gameObject, _pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.dropHandler);

            _isDragging = false;
        }
    }

    #endregion Private Methods
}
```

Comment: Excuse the confusion, but why are you assigning a value to the `_pointerEventData.position` in the first place seeing as this is assigned by Unity on certain mouse events?

Comment: Yes .. but I'm writing on my own [PointerInputModule](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerInputModule.html) like manager thing and that's the way how you pass in your own custom  pointer data to [`ExecuteEvents.Execute`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute.html) since I want to use a Controller input not a mouse ;)

Comment: Very well, thanks for clearing that up. Well I've looked at the source code for `PointerEventData` and there's nothing in there that internally modifies the `position` property other than the constructor so the problem most certainly lies in your code somewhere. The code you've shown looks fine to me, so could you perhaps provide us with some more context? Maybe the full method?

Comment: @DarrenRuane I don't think that helps much actually since this strange behaviour happens between two lines ... I had it kind of working before also with dragging but I don't see what I changed or why it shouldn't work anymore. I added the full code though it's quite complex ;) The important part happens all the way down of the `Update`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in your `_pointerEventData` property;
You are always returning a new instance of `PointerEventData` via that property, thus losing any data that you've set on the previous one.

I would suggest caching it at first like:

```
var pointerData = _pointerEventData;
pointerData.position = pointerPosition2D;
_lastPointerPosition = pointerData.position;
```

Comment: damn I'm stupid :D lol. Thanks dude .. second pair of eyes helps most of the times ^^ The way to go in this case is however to simply create it only once in `Awake` like `private PointerEventData _pointerEventData;` and then `_pointerEventData = new PointerEventData() { /* etc */}` because later I use `_pointerEventData` all over the place ^^